# How can I have two collection views on the same page

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview

I want to build two `UICollectionView` in same page. Two `UICollectionView` that would show different data as required. How could i do it?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        [self.arr addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"]];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        [self.arr2 addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"]];

    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    [flowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical];

    self.col = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds] collectionViewLayout:flowLayout];

    [self.col registerClass:[CollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCollectionCell"];

    [self.col2 registerClass:[CollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CollectionCell"];

    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout2 = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];

    [flowLayout2 setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical];

    self.col2 = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds] collectionViewLayout:flowLayout];

    [self.col2 registerClass:[CollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCollectionCell"];


    [self.col setDelegate:self];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:self.col];

    [self.col2 setDelegate:self];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:self.col2];

}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if ([collectionView isEqual:self.col2])
    {
        return self.arr2.count;
    }

    return self.arr.count;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCollectionCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (collectionView == self.col2)
    {
        cell.imageView.image = [self.arr2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    cell.imageView.image = [self.arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `else` statement here:

```
CollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView   dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCollectionCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
if (collectionView == self.col2) {
    cell.imageView.image = [self.arr2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
} else {
    cell.imageView.image = [self.arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
return cell;
```

If that doesn't work, could you be more specific on what is your problem exactly? Does one of `UICollectionView` doesn't display or displays wrong data?

EDIT:
Ok, I see you miss 2 other things:

1. Initialize `arr2`:

   ```
   self.arr2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   ```
2. You define same frame for both `UICollectionView`s:

   ```
   self.col  = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds] collectionViewLayout:flowLayout];
   self.col2 = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds] collectionViewLayout:flowLayout];
   ```

You need to define different frame, i.e.:

```
CGRect frame1 = CGRectMake(0,0,240,320);
CGRect frame2 = CGRectMake(0,320,240,320);

self.col  = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:frame1 collectionViewLayout:flowLayout];
self.col2 = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:frame2 collectionViewLayout:flowLayout];
```

This is just an example, specific depends on your usage.

**NOTE**: You should be using Autolayouts anyway, not explicit frames.

Comment: This. Otherwise, `cell.imageView.image = [self.arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` will be executed regardless of whether `collectionView == self.col2` is `true` or not (clearly not what the OP intended).

Comment: it's doesn't work because only one of CollectionView display .I check on Internet someone said is about UICollectionViewFlowLayout i couldn't use twice?!

Comment: @LiaoShangWei you create 2 different `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` so it's ok. 
In the code I see you also don't initialize `arr2`: -> self.arr2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
How do you set frames for `UICollectionView`s? I can see you use the same frame, so they cover each other....

Comment: i appreciate your advance ~~